# Weak topology and the topology of pointwise convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm reading the definition of weak topology in *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory* by Douglas:

[image]

According to an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties) about the product topology in Wikipedia, the product topology is also called topology of pointwise convergence.  I'm confused with the underscored sentence. According to the [answer by @Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/293016/9464) to the question [What is the Topology of point-wise convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/293004/9464), I was expecting

> $
> \lim_{\alpha\in A}f_\alpha=f
> $
>   if and only if $\lim_{\alpha\in A}f_\alpha(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in X$ where $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ is a net in $\mathscr{F}$.

Could anyone clarify what is going on?

Comment: The one you are referring to is the weak*-topology, while the other one is indeed the topology of point-wise convergence (weak topology)

Comment: Related Wikipedia article: [Initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).

Comment: Not sure if you already found the answer you were looking for by yourself or not, but self-studying (I hope the "self" does not scary you) things close to these, I came back to your question again (recently I also edited my answer a bit). Actually, today (better late than never) I finally saw what your problem is, and why my *answer* did not really answer your question. So, here there is the answer in very few words: it all depends on **which space** we put the **topology of pointwise convergece** (hence, my new edit – most probably you were expecting that topology on $X$ rather than $X^*$)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general we have the following definition of **initial** (or **weak**) **topology**: given a set $X \neq \varnothing$, a family of topological spaces $\{ (Y_i, \tau_i ) \}_{i \in I}$, and for every $i \in I$ a function $f_i : X \to Y_i$, the *initial* (or *weak*) *topology* is the weakest topology on $X$ that makes all the functions $f_i$ continuous.

Take the set  $\mathcal{F} := \{ f \ | \ f \in \mathbb{R}^X \}$, and notice that the weak topology on $\mathcal{F}$, denoted by $\sigma (\mathcal{F}, X)$, is identical to the relative topology on $\mathcal{F}$ as subset of $\mathbb{R}^X$ endowed with the product topology.
Moreover, notice that, given our definition of $\mathcal{F}$, the set $X$ can be seen as set of real valued functions on $\mathcal{F}$, where each $x \in X$ can be seen as an **evaluation functional** $e_x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathcal{F}$ such that $e_x (f) = f(x)$, i.e. $X = \{ \ e_x \ | \ e_x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathcal{F}, \ e_x (f) = f(x) \ \}$

Now, let $X$ a linear space with $x \in X$. Thus, let $X’$ be the *algebraic dual* of $X$, i.e. the vector space of all linear functionals on $X$, and let $X^*$ be the *topological dual* of $X$, i.e. $$X^* := \big\{ x^* \ \big| \ x^* \in \mathbb{R}^X, \ x^* \text{ continuous} \big\},$$ or – in plain english – the vector space of all continuous linear functionals on $X$, with $x^* \in X^*$.

Notationally wise, notice that, for the following, (for example) Rudin writes $\langle x , x^* \rangle \equiv x^*(x)$, thus (according to the notation employed above) we should have that $\langle x^* , x \rangle \equiv e_x (x^*)$.

Hence, $X$ can be seen (like in the second paragraph) as a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{X^*}$, in which case $\sigma (X, X^*)$ is the **weak topology** on $X$ (denoted by $w$), defined as

$$ x_\alpha \overset{w}{\to} x \in X \Longleftrightarrow \forall x^* \in X^* , \langle x_a, x^* \rangle \to \langle x , x^* \rangle \in \mathbb{R}, $$

that corresponds to the **topology of pointwise convergence** on $X^*$.

In the same vein, $X^*$ can be seen as a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^X$, in which case $\sigma (X^*, X)$ is the **weak* topology** on $X^*$ (denoted by $w^*$), defined as
$$ x^{*}_\alpha \overset{w^*}{\to} x^* \in X^* \Longleftrightarrow \forall x \in X , \langle x^{*}_a, x \rangle \to \langle x^* , x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}. $$

Notice that in both cases we are just declining in different ways the original definition of **initial topology** given at the beginning. What we are changing is simply the "reference" space that makes all functions continuous:

- In the case of the **weak topology**, we have that $(X, \sigma(X, X^*))$ is the topological space that makes all the $x^* \in X^*$ continuous;
- In the case of the **weak*** topology, we have that $(X^*, \sigma(X^*, X))$ is the topological space that makes all the *evaluation functionals* $e_x \in \mathbb{R}^{X^*}$ continuous.

---

In light of what above, the one you were expecting is the weak*-topology, and not the weak-topology. Interestingly, and here we get to the all problem of the **topology of pointwise convergence**, we can endow different spaces with that topology. In my answer (and in your book), the space endowed with that topology is $X^*$, while – most probably – your problem arose because instead you had in mind $X$ endowed with that topology.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "topology of pointwise convergence on $X^*$"? What I understand by the topology of pointwise convergence on a certain space of functions from $X$ to $Y$ is that $f_n\rightarrow f$ if and only if $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $X$. In which sense then, does the weak topology on $X$ correspond to the topology of pointwise convergence on $X^*$ (which is a collection of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$)? I would have called it the topology of pointwise convergence on $X\subset X^{**}$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, what Douglas wanted to point out with this sentence, as *pointwise convergence* is usally used in the way, Brian explains in his answer, but you can, if you want, adjust things:

Each $x \in X$ deinfes a function $\hat x$ on $\def\F{\mathscr F}\F$ by $\hat x\color \mathscr F \ni f \mapsto f(x)$. Now - by definition of $\mathscr T$ $x_\alpha \to x$ in $\mathscr T$ iff $\hat x_\alpha \to \hat x$. Thus $\mathscr T$ is (induced by) the topology of pointwise convergence on the subset $\{\hat x \mid x \in X\}$ of $Y^{\mathscr F}$.

Comment: What does $\hat xF$ mean?